# How to change the backgound color of varible of .js file during output

Tags: javascript, ajax, jscript

I am working on my project to calculate the vistors time, and i want to highlight the visitors who visit after 6:OO pm with red color and rest of them with green color in short i am trying a conditional formatting on timestamp. The variable start: moment(data.Logdate) is responsible to get the date time from database.
The code snippet is as under:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
      today: 'today',
      month: 'month',
      week: 'week',
      day: 'day'
    },
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback, Status) {
      $.ajax({
        //  url: '/Home/Index',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(result) {
          var events = [];
          $.each(result, function(i, data) {
            events.push({
              title: data.Status,
              start: moment(data.Logdate),
              //backgroundColor: "#dcdcdc",
              // color:"#000000",
              //if(moment(data.Logdate).format('HH:MM')>'18:00')backgroundColor:"#dcdcdc", else backgroundColor:"#dcdcdc"
            });
          });
          callback(events);
        }
      });
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.qtip({
        content: event.description
      });
    },
    editable: false
  });
});
```

Comment: You can make a [mcve] if you replace your AJAX with example  data

Comment: Sorry, but it isnot helpful.